# Invalid contract specified in override list?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

I am having an issue trying to deploy a contract i've just finished working on...

Here's the code :`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol';
import 'erc721a/contracts/IERC721A.sol';
import 'erc721a/contracts/extensions/erc721aQueryable.sol';


contract unNamed is ERC721AQueryable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  uint256 public constant TOTAL_MAX_SUPPLY = 10000;
  uint256 public totalFreeMints = 1000;
  uint256 public teamAmount = 777;
  uint256 public maxFreeMintPerWallet = 2;
  uint256 public maxPublicMintPerWallet = 10;
  uint256 public publicTokenPrice = .0069 ether;
  string _contractURI;

  bool public saleStarted = false;
  uint256 public freeMintCount;

  mapping(address => uint256) public freeMintClaimed;

  string private _baseTokenURI;

  constructor() ERC721A('unNamed', 'unn') {}

  modifier callerIsUser() {
    require(tx.origin == msg.sender, 'unNamed: The caller is another contract');
    _;
  }

  modifier underMaxSupply(uint256 _quantity) {
    require(
      _totalMinted() + _quantity <= TOTAL_MAX_SUPPLY - teamAmount,
      'unNamed: Purchase exceeds max supply'
    );
    _;
  }

  function mint(uint256 _quantity) external payable callerIsUser underMaxSupply(_quantity) {
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) < maxPublicMintPerWallet, "unNamed: Mint limit exceeded");
    require(saleStarted, 'unNamed: Sale has not begun ');
    if (_totalMinted() < (TOTAL_MAX_SUPPLY - teamAmount)) {
      if (freeMintCount >= totalFreeMints) {
        require(msg.value >= _quantity * publicTokenPrice, 'unNamed: Send more ETH!');
        _mint(msg.sender, _quantity);
      } else if (freeMintClaimed[msg.sender] < maxFreeMintPerWallet) {
        uint256 _mintableFreeQuantity = maxFreeMintPerWallet - freeMintClaimed[msg.sender];
        if (_quantity <= _mintableFreeQuantity) {
          freeMintCount += _quantity;
          freeMintClaimed[msg.sender] += _quantity;
        } else {
          freeMintCount += _mintableFreeQuantity;
          freeMintClaimed[msg.sender] += _mintableFreeQuantity;
          require(
            msg.value >= (_quantity - _mintableFreeQuantity) * publicTokenPrice,
            'unNamed:  Find more ETH to send'
          );
        }
        _mint(msg.sender, _quantity);
      } else {
        require(msg.value >= (_quantity * publicTokenPrice), 'unNamed: Find more ETH to send');
        _mint(msg.sender, _quantity);
      }
    }
  }

  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return _baseTokenURI;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override(ERC721A, IERC721A) returns (string memory) {
    if (!_exists(tokenId)) revert URIQueryForNonexistentToken();

    string memory baseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(baseURI).length != 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString())) : '';
  }

  function numberMinted(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    return _numberMinted(owner);
  }

  function _startTokenId() internal view virtual override returns (uint256) {
    return 1;
  }

  function ownerMint(uint256 _numberToMint) external onlyOwner underMaxSupply(_numberToMint) {
    _mint(msg.sender, _numberToMint);
  }

  function ownerMintToAddress(address _recipient, uint256 _numberToMint)
    external
    onlyOwner
    underMaxSupply(_numberToMint)
  {
    _mint(_recipient, _numberToMint);
  }

  function setFreeMintCount(uint256 _count) external onlyOwner {
    totalFreeMints = _count;
  }

  function setTeamAmount(uint256 _count) external onlyOwner {
    teamAmount = _count;
  }

  function setMaxFreeMintPerWallet(uint256 _count) external onlyOwner {
    maxFreeMintPerWallet = _count;
  }

  function setMaxPublicMintPerWallet(uint256 _count) external onlyOwner {
    maxPublicMintPerWallet = _count;
  }

  function setBaseURI(string calldata baseURI) external onlyOwner {
    _baseTokenURI = baseURI;
  }

  // Storefront metadata
  // https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata
  function contractURI() public view returns (string memory) {
    return _contractURI;
  }

  function setContractURI(string memory _URI) external onlyOwner {
    _contractURI = _URI;
  }

  function withdrawFunds() external onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }('');
    require(success, 'unNamed: Transfer failed.');
  }

  function withdrawFundsToAddress(address _address, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = _address.call{ value: amount }('');
    require(success, 'unNamed: Transfer failed.');
  }

  function flipSaleStarted() external onlyOwner {
    saleStarted = !saleStarted;
  }
}`
```

And Here's the error :

> TypeError: Invalid contract specified in override list: "IERC721A".
> --> contracts/unNamed.sol:75:58:    | 75 |   function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override(ERC721A, IERC721A) returns
> (string memory) {    |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Note: This contract:    -->
> erc721a/contracts/IERC721A.sol:10:1:    | 10 | interface IERC721A {
> | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple
> lines).
>
> Error HH600: Compilation failed

I don't see the error though, it says invalid contract specified but I have imported it as well as made sure it's in the erc721A folder...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: any help would be awesome :D i am stuuck!

Answer (score 3):

The use of the `override` keyword is no longer usable with interfaces. Remove IERC721A from `override(ERC721A, IERC721A)`

https://github.com/ethereum-optimism/optimism/pull/1491

[image]

Or just remove your upper-version indicator from your solidity version ( `^` ), that way you'll specifically use Solc 0.8.4, and i think that should do the trick as well, I hope :)